# Как сохранять видео, чтобы оно не отображалось в галерее у пользователя?

Tags: android, kotlin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то способ сохранения видео в офлайн для просмотра без интернета, но при этом чтобы оно не отображалось в галерее у пользователя?

Похожим образом сделано у "Кинопоиск" и "YouTube", там можно скачать видео и смотреть его без интернета, но и в галерее не видно.

Comment: думаю что кинопоиск шифрует свои файлы и хранит их в формате отличном от формата медиа, в связи с чем они не отображаются в галереи и их не получится открыть другим плейром.

Answer (score 1):

Большинство программ типа "Галерея" смотрят на файл с именем [`.nomedia`](https://www.lifewire.com/nomedia-file-4172882), если он есть в какой-то директории, то вся директория игнорируется от сканирования.

Если вы хотите, чтобы какая-то директория не сканировалась галереей, просто создайте в ней пустой файл с именем `.nomedia`.

В Android SDK есть константа [`MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME) со значением `".nomedia"`. Вот что сказано о ней в документации:

> Имя файла, которое указывает сканеру мультимедиа игнорировать мультимедийные файлы в содержащей его директории и всех вложенных директориях. Используйте это имя файла, чтобы избежать отображения графики в «Галерее», а также предотвратить отображение звуков и музыки в приложении «Музыка».